# Implementing a standards-compliant CSS2 Parser in C#

Tags: java, c#, c++, css

How can we parse CSS2 in C# in a standards compliant, platform agnostic (i.e. .net + mono) way?

We've built an ANTLR parser but are not satisfied with the result - it uses too much memory, and it is hard to implement the correct CSS error recovery semantics in ANTLR.

Detailed suggestions would be appreciated. CSS is decidedly *not* simple - particularly in its error recovery and forward-compatible parsing conventions. There are two grammar specifications (each with a lexer specification) that both need to somehow be implemented - [one](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#tokenization) provides error recovery and forward compatibility, [the other](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/grammar.html) embodies the detailed CSS2 specification.

The only parsers I've seen for C# are "toy" parsers that don't comply with the standard, particularly in terms of error handling and recovery and forward compatibiilty.

(For anyone planning to point us to existing code: C# is preferred, but Java or C++ could be converted by us to C#. Note that GPL or other copyleft code is *not* viable for use by us.)

[Incidentally, I don't believe this question is off topic. I've read through this [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) post and believe that this question is not a substitute for "routine search engine research." I've been looking for a good answer for over a year and am happy to list all the research I've done, but really *that* would be off-topic, since I haven't found a solution.]

Comment: Well you could write a parser yourself. CSS is pretty simple, and if you're hand-crafting a compiler it's relatively easy to customize error recovery.

Comment: Well the *semantics* are pretty complicated, but the grammar doesn't seem challenging compared to a lot of languages. All programming language grammars I know of involve a token grammar beneath the language syntax.  JavaScript is *really* nasty because of some ugly issues around regular expression syntax.

Comment: I still haven't found a solution, though. If you are suggesting one, could you please detail it? As I mention in the question, I've already built a parser, but it is not satisfactory for reasons given.

Comment: Well what I'm talking about is something like a hand-crafted recursive-descent parser. One place to look might be the source for Less or Sass, though their error recovery approaches are different from what a browser would do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60786/discussion-between-bright-and-pointy).

Comment: I don't know much about CSS parsers, but if I was setting out to write one, I'd start with the [Level 3 spec](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-syntax/) rather than the level 2 one, as that seems more detailed and more likely to match what mainstream browsers do.

Comment: That is a good suggestion. The spec you mention is much more complete now than it was when I last looked at it. Cheers.